# How to manually rearrange methods in a class with VS/Resharper?

Tags: c#, resharper

I am *specifically* trying to rediscover a feature that I have previously seen.
Does anyone recognise / know where to find, this feature?

In the past I have seen (and indeed, used) a feature of my IDE (VS + Resharper) which would pop-up a dialogue box with a list of all the methods currently in my class (and the regions, IIRC) and would allow me to drag-and-drop the methods with-in that popup window. Then when I click 'OK' (or whatever was on the button) it would automatically rearrange the methods in my class according to the changes I made.

This allows me to control and easily manage the ordering of my methods.

I'm 100% sure that this feature existed previously, and am looking to find out what it was called so that I can re-access it.

I'm ...75%? ... confident that it was a piece of R# functionality, but it *might* have been pure VS.

I would have said (maybe 20% confidence?) that the Keyboard-Shortcut at the time was Ctrl-Alt-F, but that now brings up "Resharper Code Cleanup", which appears to be a "re-order all my methods for me" dialogue? (maybe it's changed in the latest version of R#?)

Does anyone recognise this description?

---

**To Pre-empt, NO ... this is NOT a duplicate of either of these:**

- [How to reorder type members with Resharper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440131/how-to-reorder-type-members-with-resharper).
- [Resharper Clean-up Code - how to affect sorting of methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509244/resharper-clean-up-code-how-to-affect-sorting-of-methods) (hat-tip to @Alex)

Those question are about how to get Resharper to *automatically* sort your methods, based on rigid configured rules, which isn't the feature that I'm remembering.

- I'm not interested in the IDE deciding on the ordering or applying some preset ordering for me - I want to keep full control.
- I'm not interested in installing some tool other than VS or Resharper.
- I'm not trying to remember the shortcuts for moving methods one at a time (Ctrl-Alt-Shift-{ArrowKey})

I am *specifically* trying to rediscover a feature that I have previously seen.

Comment: This used to be a feature of both R# (a long time ago, perhaps v6.0) and MZTools. R# definitely doesn't do it anymore, not sure about MZTools

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 aww shucks. That would be really sad :( I don't suppose you can find anything referencing the prior functionality in R#, so that I can check that I'm thinking of the same thing as you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the past I have seen (and indeed, used) a feature of my IDE (VS + Resharper) which would pop-up a dialogue box with a **list of all the methods currently in my class (and the regions**, IIRC) and would allow me to **drag-and-drop** the methods with-in that popup **window**.

The closest thing I can think of is ReSharper's **File Structure** window.  To open it select **ReSharper.Windows.File Structure** or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> (in my environment anyway).

[image]

The File Structure window appears.  This is a live overview of the current source file (works with **.cs** as well as other files like **.xaml**).   For **.cs** files you can drag and drop class members around in the file.

[image]

- Want to apply your own manual **method ordering**?  You can do that
- Want to put fields at the top.  You can do that
- Want to create/edit/delete **regions** for your methods.  You can do that too

To move a member around just **drag and drop** it.

[image]

OP:

> Then when I click 'OK' (or whatever was on the button) it would automatically rearrange the methods in my class according to the changes I made.

File Structure doesn't do any anything automatically.  Perhaps you are thinking of *Code Cleanup*?  That is still present in R#.

Comment: Ah hah! That's the one! Appears to now be bound to Ctrl-F11 for reasons unknown. My use of the word "automatically" in that last bit you quoted was poorly chosen and misleading. I actually just mean `When I click OK it will rearrange the methods`.